# group and modify rows by index python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a question on pandas-python:
Say I have a column with 1000+ elements (integers), and its name is 'a' like

```
'a' = [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,..............]
```

I want to modify the elements by row index(every third number increase by 1 till the end of the column), and deleting the name. My final (and desired) output wold be:

```
'b' = [2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5..................]
```

Any hint?

Comment: welcome to stack overflow! please see the guide on [ask] - specifically, please do not write pseudocode if your question is about python implementation. Instead, try to develop a [mre], showing us what you've tried and what's not working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way of solving this, but the given code works:

```
    import pandas as pd

    alist = []
    
    for i in range(0,1000):
       alist.append(2)
  
    data = {'a':alist}
    dataset = pd.DataFrame(data)

    count = 2

    for i in range(0, (len(alist)//3), 3):
       dataset.iloc[i: i+3 ] = count
       count = count + 1
```

I have looped through the dataframe a third of the total times while increasing the loop count by 3 and at every position used iloc to replace the value of the given column of the current row as well as the 2 after it with a variable count which was initialized from 2 and incremented at each step.

Comment: Thank you very much Ayush, great solution! I tried one or two answers but didnt get the right one.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
c = []
for i in range(0, len(a), 3):
    b = a[i : i + 3]
    for j in range(len(b)):
        b[j] = b[j] + (i // 3)
    c.extend(b)
print(c)
```

Comment: Very clever, and it worked really nice, thank you!